# Append data from multiple files to matlab array

Tags: matlab, file-io, matrix, append

Hello i need you help to append all the data i read from many files into a matrix. I have made the following script

```
path='C:\Users\Kostas\Documents\MATLAB\';
filefolder=strcat(path,'MSL*.txt');
files=dir(filefolder);
k=0;
for i=1:length(files)
    filename=strcat(path,files(i).name);    
    %load the filename and create vectors of height (Z),
    %lat and lon
    newData=importdata(filename,'\t', 1);
    vars = fieldnames(newData);
for j = 1:length(vars)
    assignin('base', vars{j}, newData.(vars{j}));
end 
    timeas=data(:,1);
    lat=data(:,2);
    lon=data(:,3);
    Z=data(:,4);
  %  daten=(timeas/24)+doy;
   k=k+1; 
%append data to matrix Teff_series
    Teff_series(k,:)= [timeas lat lon Z];
end
```

the error message i get when i run this script is

```
??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in ==> te at 31
    Teff_series(k,:)= [lat lon Z];
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give an example:

```
%# get the list of files
fpath = 'C:\Users\Amro\Desktop\';
files = dir( fullfile(fpath,'file*.dat') );
files = strcat(fpath,{files.name}');

%# read data from all files and store in cell array
Teff_series = cell(numel(files),1);
for i=1:numel(files)
    newData = importdata(files{i}, '\t', 1);
    Teff_series{i} = newData.data;
end

%# combine all into a matrix
data = vertcat(Teff_series{:});
colNames = newData.colheaders;

%# extract columns as vectors
t = data(:,1);
lat = data(:,2);
lon = data(:,3);
Z = data(:,4);
```

If I use these sample data files:

#### file1.dat

```
t   lat lon Z
1   2   3   4
2   3   4   5
4   5   6   6
```

#### file2.dat

```
t   lat lon Z
4   5   6   6
2   3   4   5
1   2   3   4
```

I get the following results:

```
>> colNames
colNames = 
    't'    'lat'    'lon'    'Z'

>> data
data =
     1     2     3     4
     2     3     4     5
     4     5     6     6
    40    50    60    60
    20    30    40    50
    10    20    30    40
```

Comment: `i` as variable should be avoided. It is used as the complex number `> i` shows it: `0.0000 + 1.0000i`

Comment: @JonasStein: right but you also could argue the opposite of never using `i` as the imaginary unit, instead always use [`1i`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/i.html) whenever you are referring to the complex number, thus avoiding any confusion.. Either way, this was discussed [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab) :)

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the left hand side of the equal expression - in this case:
    Teff_series(k, :)

is of a different size than the right hand side:

```
[lat lon Z]
```

One way to debug this issue is execute the command:

```
dbstop if all error
```

and then re-run your script. It will stop the debugger at the point where the error is thrown and then you can figure out the difference in sizes.

Hope this helps.